# `getLastPageNumber()` returning wrong number of pages

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, product-collection, pagination

For some reason, using `$collection->getLastPageNumber()` is returning the wrong number of pages.

For example:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('link_table' => 'catalog_product_super_link'),'link_table.product_id = e.entity_id',
            array('product_id','parent_id')
        );
$collection->getSelect()->group('link_table.parent_id');
```

I'm not quite sure what the issue might be. I'm using joinLeft and group on my collection, as seen above. As far as I can tell, it's the only thing 'out of the ordinary' that I'm doing.

When I debugged the query, it returned, for example, 625 rows. But, using a pagelimit of 10, and then calling `getLastPageNumber()` returns a total of 325 pages, instead of 62 pages!

What might be causing such an issue?

***EDIT:
The query is:***

> SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_visibility.value_id > 0, at_visibility.value, at_visibility_default.value) AS `visibility`, `link_table`.`product_id`, `link_table`.`parent_id`, `color_t1`.`attribute_id`, `color_t1`.`value`, `color_t1`.`store_id`, `at_stock_status`.`stock_status`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility_default` ON (`at_visibility_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility_default`.`attribute_id` = '102') AND `at_visibility_default`.`store_id` = 0
>    LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility` ON (`at_visibility`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility`.`attribute_id` = '102') AND (`at_visibility`.`store_id` = 1)
>    LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_super_link` AS `link_table` ON link_table.product_id = e.entity_id
>    LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `color_t1` ON color_t1.entity_id = e.entity_id AND color_t1.store_id = 0 AND color_t1.attribute_id = 92
>    LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `at_stock_status` ON (at_stock_status.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (at_stock_status.stock_id=1)
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = '1' WHERE (IF(at_visibility.value_id > 0, at_visibility.value, at_visibility_default.value) = '1') GROUP BY `link_table`.`parent_id`,
>           `color_t1`.`value`

Comment: did you try getLastPageNum();

Comment: can you please show query of collection by `$collection->getSelect()->__toString();`

Comment: @AmitBera I added the collection in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You are directly operating on `Zend_Db_Select` which is always a bad idea.

The thing here is, that `getLastPageNumber` is using `getSize`, which is `\Varien_Data_Collection_Db::getSize` and uses `\Varien_Data_Collection_Db::getSelectCountSql` which is overwritten here `\Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::getSelectCountSql` and implemented with `\Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::_getSelectCountSql`.

Digging deeper in this methods shows:

```
protected function _getSelectCountSql($select = null, $resetLeftJoins = true)
{
    $this->_renderFilters();
    $countSelect = (is_null($select)) ?
        $this->_getClearSelect() :
        $this->_buildClearSelect($select);
    $countSelect->columns('COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id)');
    if ($resetLeftJoins) {
        $countSelect->resetJoinLeft();
    }
    return $countSelect;
}
```

And I assume your problem is:

```
    if ($resetLeftJoins) { // true by default
        $countSelect->resetJoinLeft();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per as query,on your collection, pager and page Size not   implemented.

If you want to get page no then  need to use `setPageSize()` to your `collection` for getting total  page number & last page no. With out  set Page size you does not get last page number.

For how to implement pager check

- [excellencemagentoblog](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/18/magento-collection-paging/)
- [devinrolsen](http://www.devinrolsen.com/magento-adding-pagination-to-custom-collection/)

Comment: I'm using `setPageSize()` and it's returning the products and pages correctly. (It stops showing products after page 11) But the page number is still returning wrong and saying there are 33 pages..